# WCF with transport authentication using certificates and message authentication using username/password

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm trying to configure a WCF service to implement two factor authentication.  The idea being that there would be message level authentication with a username/password (WS security) and transport level authentication using a client certificate.

**Step 1: Message level authentication**

I've built a WCF service that uses message level authentication with username/password.  All works great.  I see the credentials passed from the client in the soap header and the service authenticates and authorizes the user.

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity type and has the following property values:

- AuthenticationType = Basic
- ImpersonationLevel = Impersonation
- IsAnonymous = false
- IsAuthenticated = true
- Name = my ad account (DOMAIN\accountname)

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity object is also a windowsIdentity and has the same property values as above.

**Step 2: Transport level authentication with certificates**

Then I built a new WCF service that uses transport authentication with certificates.  Again, all works great.

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity object is a System.IdentityModel.Claims.X509Identity type and has the following property values:

- AuthenticationType = X509
- IsAuthenticated = true
- Name = the subject attribute of the certificate, thumbprint

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity type and has the following property values:

- Authentication Type = ""
- ImpersonationLevel = Anonymous
- IsAnonymous = true
- IsAuthenticated = false

**Step 3: Transport level authentication with certificates & active directory mapping**

Next, I turned on active directory mapping by creating a service behavior and setting the serviceCredientials\clientCertificate\authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount attribute to true.

The service appears to correctly map the certificate to my active directory account.

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity type and has the following property values:

- AuthenticationType = SSL/PCT
- ImpersonationLevel = Identification
- IsAnonymous = false
- IsAuthenticated = true
- Name = my ad account (DOMAIN\accountname)

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity object is also a windowsIdentity and has the same property values as above.

**Step 4:  Message level authentication and transport authentication**

With the above scenarios working, I now want to combine them.  A created a web service with username password message level authentication and certificate transport authentication, with Active Directory user mapping disabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>    
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFTransportAuthCertificateMessageAuthUserName.Service1"
               behaviorConfiguration="MapClientCertificates">
        <endpoint binding="customBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="TransportCertificateAuthentication_MessageUserNameAuthenticiation"
                  contract="WCFTransportAuthCertificateMessageAuthUserName.IService1">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>    
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="TransportCertificateAuthentication_MessageUserNameAuthenticiation">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"></security>
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"></httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="MapClientCertificates">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="false" includeWindowsGroups="true" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity type and has the following property values:

- Authentication Type = ""
- IsAuthenticated = false
- Name = ""

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity object is a System.IdentityModel.Claims.X509Identity type and has the following property values:

- AuthenticationType = X509
- IsAuthenticated = true
- Name = the subject attribute of the certificate, thumbprint

**So at this point, I can see details of the certificate credentials, but not of the message credentials.  That is my first question - why can't I see the message level credentials?**

**Step 5:  Message level authentication and transport authentication with AD mapping.**

Now I turn on AD user mapping by setting the serviceCredientials\clientCertificate\authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount attribute to true.

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity type and has the following property values:

- Authentication Type = ""
- IsAuthenticated = false
- Name = ""

The System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity object is a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity type and has the following property values:

- AuthenticationType = ""
- ImpersonationLevel = Anonymous
- IsAuthenticated = false
- IsAnonymous = true
- Name = ""

Authentication appears to be happening correctly at both the transport and message level.  If I specify the incorrect username/password in the soap header, I will get a soap fault back.  If I do not provide a client certificate, or provide an untrusted one, I also get an error
**So here, I understand that the System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity would be a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity type because the service is configured to map to an AD account, but why did it not actually map?**